# How to commit to the develop branch in RedGate SQL Source Control

Tags: git, redgate

In the Commit tab, the branch shown is a grey **master**.

[image]

In my GitHub, I have already set up a **develop** branch and hope to commit my changes to that branch. How can I change the working branch in RedGate SQL Source Control?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do branch switching within SQL Source Control, at least not yet. For now you have to use an external client such as the Git command line.

Eg, git checkout yourbranch

After you do this you will need to update your database by going to the get latest tab in SQL Source Control.

Answer (score 2):

Based on David Atkinson's answer, I gave up doing branch switching within SQL Source Control.

Here is what I did.

1. Clone the git,

```
git clone ...
```

At this moment, there is only one **master** branch in the local git repository.

```
git branch -l
```

But the **develop** branch can be seen in `remotes/origin/develop`

```
git branch -a
```

2. Copy the **develop** branch from remote to local repository.

```
git branch -c develop
git branch -l
```

Now we will see both **develop** and **master** branches in local repository.

3. switch to **develop** branch in local repository

```
git switch develop
git branch -l
```

4. Unlink database in SQL Source Control and Link database to SQL Source Control again.
   [image: success]

Now the branch in SQL Source Control is **develop**. It is greyed and cannot be changed to other branch.

That is my "solution" in the year of 2020. Let's hope RedGate can provide a easier way to switch branch in the future.